# How to push an optional path and parameter to vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

On an ecommerce project, I have a category page with optional url parameters, and a product page. I'd like to add a string to the optional parameter to avoid a collision with the product, like so:

```
routes: [
        {
            path: '/:category/(item-colour/:colour)?/(usage/:usage)?/',
            name: 'category',
            component: Category,
            props: true,
        },
        {
            path: '/:category/:product',
            name: 'product',
            component: Product,
            props: true,
        },
    ],
```

But when I go to push the optional parameters, I can't also push the string.

```
push() {
            let routeParams = {
                category: this.category,
            }

            Object.assign(routeParams, 
                this.selectedColours.length > 1 ? {colour: this.selectedColours} : null,
                this.selectedUsage.length > 1 ? {usage: this.selectedUsage} : null,
            )

            this.$router.push({ name: 'category', 
                params: routeParams
            })
        }
```

Comment: what is the value of one of your variables `this.selectedColors` for example?

Comment: "Red, Blue, Green" - One or multiple, split by a comma.

Comment: I think you would need to write it like this:
`
path: `/:category/'(item-colour/':colour')'?/'(usage/':usage')'?/`,
`

Comment: Thanks. Sadly my router now sends me to the default. Are you wrapping the strings and closing parenthesis in single quotes?